# ko.pureComputed - clear cached value on sleep

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have some `ko.pureComputed` properties that usually hold a big amount of data inside themselves. 
When those `ko.pureComputed` properties go to *sleeping* state (noone is subscribe to them) I don't need that data anymore until they go back to *listening* state (someone is subscribe to them).

During that time while they are in the *sleeping* state I'd like the `ko.pureComputed` properties to clear their values so that the garbage collector can remove that computed data from memory, then when I need the computed data again, that is, when the `ko.pureComputed` go back into *listening* state, I'd like to reevalute the computed data.

Is that possible?

**Further details about my use-case scenario:**

My site is a Single Page Application, meaning a Javascript framework (*Durandal*) switches pages (HTML and JS) in display for the user.

Some pages have a need for computed properties which would store large amount of data. I'd like to use `ko.pureComputed` for that purpose, because it will stop updating itself once the user goes off its page, i.e. once the `ko.pureComputed` goes into *sleep* state because it has no more listeners.

(*Durandal* deattaches and reattaches the page's JS viewmodel from and into the HTML view when the user goes away or visits the page)

The problem is that the `ko.pureComputed` keeps its latest value cached.
In my case those values are large arrays of large objects, which take up a noticeable amount of memory. I'd like to dispose of that data once it's not needed anymore.

Is there a way to clear the cached value from the `ko.pureComputed` once it goes into the *sleeping* state (when the user leaves the page), and then later reinitialize it when the `ko.pureComputed` goes back to *listening* state (when the user revisits the page)?

Comment: If the pure computed were really transitioning from sleeping to listening, it would recalcuate its value according to [the docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-pure.html) (and my personal experience). So I suspect something *else* is going on (but have no idea what, never seen Durandal).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder 
The question I'm asking is how to clear the cached data when the pure Computed goes to sleep.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder also, per the docs, it will only reevalute if the observables it subscribe to have changed while it was sleeping.

Comment: *"... and later reinitialize it when the ko.pureComputed goes back to listening state..."* My point being: If you're seeing a stale value, I don't think it's because of the pure computed's state changing from listening -> sleeping or sleeping -> listening, I think it's something *else*.

Comment: There is no stale value problem. 
My problem is that I don't want my ko.pureComputeds' cached values to stay in memory when I don't need them. I'd like to clear their cached values when the user leaves the page, put them to sleep, then when the user comes back I'd like to reevaluate and put the ko.pureComputeds back into listening mode.

Comment: Are you using durandal's router library to switch pages or are you swapping view-models in-place using the compose binding?

Comment: @JasonSpake the router library.

Comment: There is a possibility to track state changes: see [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-pure.html) (the last example with "asleep" option)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a pure computed's state change events, we can tell the computed to clear its value while it's sleeping. Here's a wrapper function that sets it all up:

```
function computedValueOnlyWhenActive(readFunction) {
    var isAwake = ko.observable(false),
        theComputed = ko.pureComputed(function () {
            if (isAwake()) {
                return readFunction();
            }       
        });

    theComputed.subscribe(function() {
        isAwake(true);
    }, undefined, "awake");
    theComputed.subscribe(function() {
        isAwake(false);
        theComputed.peek(); // force reevaluation
    }, undefined, "asleep");

    return theComputed;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mbest/gttosLzc/

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer to the specific question you asked, but it might be a more helpful answer depending on your situation.

In Durandal the router plugin navigates by asynchronously loading the specified module with a requireJS call. Once it retrieves the module it checks if the result is either an object or a function, and if it's a function it will instantiate a new object from the function. If it is an object it just uses the object.

RequireJS automatically caches the modules it retrieves in that it doesn't bother re-fetching a module from the server if it's already downloaded it. So if your module definition is a plain object then that same object will get displayed each time.

This module definition will save its state between navigations:

```
define(['durandal/app'], function (app) {
    var title = 'myView';
    var vm = {
        title: title;
    };

    return vm;
});
```

This module definition will create a new object and will re-bind all knockout bindings resulting in a freshly loaded screen on each navigation.

```
define(['durandal/app'], function (app) {
    var title = 'myView';
    var vm = function(){
        this.title = title;
    };

    return vm;
});
```

**EDIT:**
For a more granular durandal solution that also works with older versions of knockout (i.e. before pureComputed) you can combine the concept in michael best's answer of using an isAwake observable with durandal's view activation and deactivation lifecycle hooks.

```
function viewModel(){
    var self = this;
    this.isAwake = ko.observable(true);

    this.theComputed = ko.computed(function () {
        if (isAwake()) {
            return myValue();
        }       
        return "";
    });

    this.activate = function(){
        self.isAwake(true);
    }
    this.deactivate = function(){
        self.isAwake(false);
    }
}
var vm = new viewModel();
return vm; //return the instance not the function
```

http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks.html

Comment: Clever approach and thanks for trying, but I do need to keep some data between page visits (user preferences), just not the 2 big collections of data.
If it can't be done with an elegant KO approach, I will consider breaking my page up into two modules, one that keeps data, and one that gets reinitialized every time.